# Python 3 script not writing to Postgres table

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, insert, psycopg2

The first part of the script returns all of my AD users with values converted to Python str: draft = [('Display Name', 'username'),]

I want to write this to my main_associate table (Postgres 9.5) avoiding duplicates. I know I have records in the list that are not duplicates and should be written. This returns no errors but doesn't write my records:

```
try:
    new_conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' user='usr' host='localhost' password='pswd'")
except:
    print("Unable to connect to the associates database.")

sql = """INSERT INTO main_associate(displayname,username) VALUES(%s,%s)
    ON CONFLICT (username) DO NOTHING"""

one_cur = new_conn.cursor()
for grp in draft:
    #print(grp)
    one_cur.execute(sql, (grp[0],grp[1],))
    new_conn.commit

one_cur.close()
new_conn.close()
```

Comment: Typo: `new_conn.commit()`

Comment: That was it. missed the empty brackets. That was driving me crazy! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you install sqlalchemy...

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:pswd@localhost/test')
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)
table = meta.tables['main_associate']

for grp in draft:
    ins = table.insert({"displayname":grp[0],"username":grp[1]}).on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=['username'])
    engine.execute(ins)
```